# width:auto overwrite inline width of image

Tags: html, css, wordpress

A client asked me to look into a problem he is having on his WP site.
When adding an external image into a post, with an original size of 800x640.
You can resize the image via the Wordpress wysiwyg editor to, say 400x320.
the html part will look something like this when inspecing the element with firebug on front end or in the text tab of the editor:

```
<img class="" src="http://xxx.nl/images/externalimage.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="320" />
```

But on the front end the image is shown at its original 800x640 size.
When inspecting the element with firebug it shows:

```
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: auto;
}
```

If I disable the 'width' line in firebug
The image resizes to 400x320.

How can I resolve this issue, so that the client can just do his thing with the images in the editor.

I can solve it myself on a individual case basis by adding a width to the containing span/p tag, but the client doesn't know css or html and I can't manually edit all the widths of the containing tags every time he posts something new.

The images will always be inside the 'post' wrap container, which has its own class. But apart from auto, I only set it to 'inherit' but this yields the same result as auto. (I guess it will inherit -> auto from the img {})

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, seems quite an easy question.

Comment: why are you setting a global css to the img element. That creates a slew of issues.. Just remvoe that from the CSS.

Comment: If the images your client add are always wrapped by `.post` wrapper you can try adding the style you applied on the individual case basis to the style.css file

Comment: Do those styles need to be on img? Do you have access to the css? Just delete that width style if it doesn't affect everything else. Like Cam said there really shouldn't be those general styles on every image anyways

Comment: My problem is, that I didn't build the site, or the theme. The global css to img element is from the theme. Removing it changes several layouts on the site. But that might be the only solution, removing it. Fix all the broken layouts...

@FayçalArab thats the whole point of the question, I could solve it on individual bases, but then I have to do this every time he posts something. Thats not a workable solution for me or the client.